# Heap has been corrupted

Tags: c++, input, heap-corruption

In my main function I call inputHolding 5 times.  It goes through a couple loops and then it gives me an error saying the heap has been corrupted when it tries to read in the callNumber, usually on the third loop.  How do I fix this crash?

```
Holding* inputHolding() {
char selection;
char title[50];
int callNumber = 0;
char author[50];
char performer[50];
char format;

cout << "Enter B for book, R for recording: ";
cin >> selection;

if (selection == 'B') {
    cout << "Enter book title: ";
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Enter book author: ";
    cin >> author;

    cout << "Enter call number: ";
    cin >> callNumber;

    Book* muhbooksie = new Book(title, callNumber, author);
    return muhbooksie;
}
else  if (selection == 'R') {
    cout << "Enter recording title: ";
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Enter performer: ";
    cin >> performer;

    cout << "Enter format: (M)P3, (W)AV, (A)IFF: ";
    cin >> format;

    cout << "Enter call number: ";
    cin >> callNumber;

    Recording* muhbooksie = new Recording(title, callNumber, performer,     format);
    return muhbooksie;
}
else {
    cout << "Incorrect selection" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
}
```

Book.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Holding.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "String.h"

using namespace std;

Book::Book() {

}

Book::Book(const Book& copy) : Holding(copy) {
author = new char[strlen(copy.author) + 1];

strcpy_s(author, sizeof(author), copy.author);
}

Book::Book(char* inputTitle, int inputCallNum, char* inputAuthor) : Holding(inputTitle,     inputCallNum) {
int len = strlen(inputAuthor) + 1;
author = new char[len];

strcpy_s(author, sizeof(author)*len, inputAuthor);
}

Book::~Book() {
delete [] author;
}

void Book::print() {
cout << "BOOK: " << author << " " << title << " " << callNumber << endl;
}
```

Comment: your title/author etc variables are only 50 charsacters. So if you enter more that that cin is writing outside of the array bounds which is bad.

Comment: use object of string class instead of char array that will help

Comment: ... and use smart pointers, Luck :)

Comment: Please show us the Book and Recording classes, esp. the constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 1):

With everything said in the comment section of the question, you should (for the Book class):

- Overload the '=' operator,
- Implement the 'copy and swap' idiom,
- And initialize 'author' at nullptr in the default constructor and check the value in the destructor.

This way, your code will be cleaner and for example if the default constructor is used, the destructor will not delete an unspecified author.